# Numerical integration with a fixed sampling size, skipping points

Tags: core-language

I have a large number of data points to integrate over numerically. I would like to sample only some of the points and use a rather large step size just to reduce computation time.

Say the data points are indexed along the x-axis and each point is separated by 1. And say I would like to use a sampling size of 10. So, I only use data points with `x=10,20,30...`. What is the syntax for this in Mathematica?

I am sure this is a very basic question, but the answer eludes me.

Edit: I need to be able to set different step sizes in different intervals, so I do not exactly need partitioning the *data*. I was wondering if there is a way to directly specify the sampling on given data.

Comment: `Part` and `Span`: `Range[100][[;;;;10]]`

Answer (score 1):

Partition, for example

```
data = Table[{x, x^3}, {x, 0, 100}];

data2 = Flatten[Partition[data, 1, 10], 1]
```

Comment: This seems to modify the entire data directly. I need to be able to set different sampling accuracy in different intervals, hence the question about choosing the sampling, rather than just abridging the data. Could this be done?

Answer (score 1):

```
data = Range[0, 100];
Downsample[data, 10]
```

> {0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100}

Comment: This seems to modify the entire data directly. I need to be able to set different sampling accuracy in different intervals, hence the question about choosing the sampling, rather than just abridging the data. Could this be done?